# Gibt es kein deutsches Wort für "abstract"?

Tags: anglicism

Heute hat mir ein Schüler erzählt, dass in einer Aufgabe im Deutsch-Abitur verlangt war, einen "abstract" zu erstellen. Mich wundert es, dass in einem Deutsch-Abitur ein englischer Begriff verwendet wird und hätte gedacht, dass man einfach auch nach einer "Zusammenfassung" hätte fragen können. Wäre diese Übersetzung unzutreffend? Was wäre die korrekte Übersetzung? Oder gibt es kein äquivalentes deutsches Wort dazu?

Comment: Der Duden kanonisiert das Denglisch: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abstract :-(

Comment: @Matthias Tatsache ist, dass der Duden seit längerer Zeit kein "offizielles" Werk mehr ist, sondern nur noch ein von einer Privatfirma herausgegebenes Buch.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: na und? Man kann den Duden doch trotzdem noch erwähnen, wie andere Wörterbücher auch. Oder enthält der Duden ungewöhnlich viele Fehler?

Comment: Takkat: Das nicht, aber der Duden steht seit 21 Jahren nicht mehr über seinen Mitbewerbern.

Comment: @Takkat Das Problem dabei ist, dass viele Leute denken: "Wenn es im Duden steht, muss es richtiges Deutsch sein." Das simmt aber nicht.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: dann ist das Problem doch eher die Leute und nicht der  Duden, oder? Die Güte unserer Aussagen gewinnt, wenn wir unsere Behauptungen durch eine fundierte Quelle belegen. Ich halte den Duden  für eine solche. Antworten oder Kommentare, die auf jegliche Belege verzichten, sind ein viel ernsteres Problem, da wir hier eine rein persönliche Behauptung aufstellen und vielleicht sogar meinen, dass sie durch eine Abstimmung weniger User unserer Community ausreichend belegt sind.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Wer legt denn fest, was "richtiges Deutsch" ist (wenn nicht der Duden)? Du? Der Duden beschreibt jedenfalls, dass das Wort gebräuchlich ist und von einer Vielzahl kompetenter Sprecher*innen des Deutschen verwendet wird.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Zu dieser Frage gibt es ein Urteil des Bundesverfassungsgerichts aus dem Jahr 1998. Demnach legen die Landesregierungen fest, was in Schulen und Behörden als "richtiges Deutsch" gilt. In der Zeit kurz danach war es tatsächlich so, dass in Schleswig-Holstein etwas Anderes als "richtiges Deutsch" galt als im Rest Deutschlands. Hintergrund war eine Volksabstimmung zur Rechtschreibreform in jenem Land. Wer festlegt, was außerhalb von Schulen und Behörden als "richtiges Deutsch" gilt, lässt das Urteil offen. Der Duden jedenfalls nicht.

Answer (score 7):

Eine

> Zusammenfassung

ist entweder

- eine kurzer Text **in einem anderen Dokument** als dem ursprünglichen, in dem der Inhalt des ursprünglichen Dokuments start gekürzt wiedergegeben wird. Für gewöhnlich hat eine solche externe Zusammenfassung einen anderen Urheber als das zusammengefasste Werk.

oder

- ein Abschnitt **am Ende** eines Dokuments, in dem die wichtigsten Inhalte des Dokuments (oft aus didaktischen Gründen) verdichtet wiederholt werden.

---

Ein

> Abstract

ist aber

- ein Abschnitt **am Beginn** eines (meist wissenschaftlichen) Dokuments, der eine verdichtete Vorschau auf den eigentlichen Inhalt des Dokuments liefert. Dieser Abschnitt wird häufig in Übersichtsdokumenten und Dokumentenverzeichnissen wortwörtlich zitiert.

Der Abstract einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit kann auch bei einer elektronischen Suche in wissenschaftlichen Datenbanken durchsucht werden, während der eigentliche Text der Arbeit üblicherweise nicht vom Suchalgorithmus erfasst wird.

---

Ein *Abstract* ist daher etwas anderes als eine *Zusammenfassung*. Ein gebräuchliches deutsches Wort für *Abstract* kenne ich nicht.

Comment: Somit unterscheidet sich *Zusammenfassung* und *Abstract* im Wesentlichen in der Stellung im Text? Demnach kann man in einer Abiturarbeit aber keinen *Abstract* zu einem gegebenen Text verlangen, da das (möchtegern-)*Abstract* dann ja von einem anderen Urheber erstellt wurde. Ferner habe ich schon öfters in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten gesehen, die auf deutsch erschienen sind, dass statt *abstract* das Wort *Zusammenfassung* verwendet wird. Teilweise gibt es in solchen deutschen Arbeiten dann auch eine englische Zusammenfassung, die *abstract* heißt.

Comment: @Julia: Nein, die Stellung im Text ist nicht wesentlich. Das ist nur ein auffallendes Merkmal. Auch die Urheberschaft ist nicht wesentlich. Wesentlich ist der unterschiedliche Zweck: Die Zusammenfassung, sofern sie im selben Dokument steht, richtet sich an Leser, die das gesamte Dokument schon kennen. Der Zweck: Wiederholung der Highlights. Ein Abstract richtet sich an jemanden, der das Werk nicht kennt, und anhand des Abstracts entscheiden will, ob er das gesamte Dokument lesen (und vorher häufig gezwungenermaßen kaufen) soll.

Comment: In einer Matura- oder Abitur-Arbeit kann man meiner Meinung nach sehr wohl verlangen, einen fremden Text zu einem Abstract zu verdichten, weil damit offenbar nachgewiesen werden soll, ob der Prüfling in der Lage ist, aus einem Werk jene Inhalte herauszuarbeiten, die einem potentiellen Leser helfen können zu entscheiden, ob er das ganze Dokument lesen soll. Im »wirklichen Leben« macht das natürlich der Autor des Werks selbst, aber in einer Prüfung kann ich mir durchaus vorstellen, dass man die Fähigkeit einen Abstract zu erstellen, auf diese Weise abprüft.

Comment: Auch Zusammenfassungen außerhalb des Ursprungsdokuments haben im Normalfall nicht das Ziel, einem potentiellen Leser eine Hilfe bei der Entscheidung zu geben, ob er den Volltext lesen soll. Genau diese Aufgabe hat aber ein Abstract.

Answer (score 4):

Ich halte *Zusammenfassung* für eine ziemlich genaue Übersetzung von *abstract*, was auch von von den Verwendungsbeispielen bei [Pons](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=abstract&l=deen&in=&lf=en#examples-Adeen748087) gestützt wird. Der englische Begriff benötigt ebenso wie der deutsche eine genauere Erläuterung, also etwa "wie sie vor einem ausführlicheren Artikel zu dem Thema stehen könnte."

Dass es sich um einen Begriff der Fachsprache handelt ist unstrittig, deren Kenntnis kann man aber bei einem Abiturienten vermutlich nicht zwingend voraussetzen (es sei denn, die Lehrpläne hätten sich in diese Richtung deutlich erweitert). Da der Begriff auch fachsprachlich mehrdeutig ist (Philosophie),
ist die zusätzliche Erläuterung ohnehin geboten, und dann bringt der Fachbegriff gegenüber der deutschen Entsprechung keinen zusätzlichen Erkenntnisgewinn.

Comment: Welche fachsprachlichen Mehrdeutigkeiten gibt es denn? Gibt es jeweils eine 1:1 Entsprechung im Deutschen?

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia beschreibt einen [Abstract](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract) als "prägnante Inhaltsangabe". Der Artikel verweist auch auf die DIN 1426, in der der (oder das) "Abstract" als Kurzreferat zur Inhaltsangabe beschrieben wird. Der Begriff "Abstract" ist demnach ein Synonym zum "Kurzreferat".

Der Artikel verweist auf die [Inhaltsangabe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhaltsangabe), die Gegenstand der genannten Norm ist. Die DIN definiert als Formen von Inhaltsangaben

- das Inhaltsverzeichnis
- das Abstract
- andere Formen dokumentarischer Referate.

Somit wäre **Inhaltsangabe** ein treffender deutscher Begriff. Wobei ich den Vorschlag "Zusammenfassung" spontan als genauso richtig bezeichnet hätte.

Answer (score 2):

'Abstract' ist ein *terminus technicus* und wird daher als Lehnwort ins Deutsche übernommen. Die Domäne, aus der der Begriff stammt - die Naturwissenschaften -, ist englischsprachig dominiert; eine Übersetzung empfiehlt sich daher nicht. 'Abstract' ist der eindeutige Begriff für die vom Autor selbst verfasste Kurzfassung eines wissenschaftlichen Artikels der vor dem Artikel steht und von Journals verlangt und als Bestandteil des Artikels publiziert wird). Übersetzungen würden hier Uneindeutigkeit bringen.

Diese Übernahme von *termini technici* ist ein in der Sprachgeschichte häufig anzutreffendes Phänomen. Ein Beispiel dafür ist etwa der Begriff 'terminus technicus' selbst :-)

Comment: Wird aber in der Tat auf deutsch übersetzt z.B. bei Springer: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01341423?LI=true

Comment: Oder hier: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-26737-0_11

Comment: @Julia In deinen Beispielen ist der Begriff durch den Kontext vereindeutigt. (NB: Bei dem Hilbert-Beispiel ist der Zusatz nachträglich von Springer eingefügt worden - s. http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-26737-0_11#page-1) Für eine Abituraufgabe (das Beispielszenario aus der Frage) gilt dennoch, dass mit "Schreiben Sie einen Abstract!" die geforderte Textsorte eindeutiger bezeichnet wiurd, als mit "Schreiben Sie eine Zusammenfassung!".

Comment: @Julia Die Eindeutschung des Springer-Verlags halte ich für sehr unglücklich, ein Abstract ist eher ein sachlich gehaltener Klappentext und enthält in der Regel nur inhaltliche Eckpunkte (Thema, Methodologie, Ergebnis, Bedeutung). Man kann das zwar als sehr grobe Zusammenfassung ansehen, würde bei Verwendung des Begriffs aber eher einen Text erwarten, der Struktur und Argumentation des Artikels nachzuvollziehen erlaubt.